# values populated using jquery lost on server side validation mvc4

Tags: jquery, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

View

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PracticGropupId, new SelectList(Model.PracticeGroup, "Value", "Text"))
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SubPracticeGroupId, Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), new { style = "width:250px;" })
```

JS

```
$('#PracticGropupId').change(function () {

    var selectedGroupId = $(this).val();

    $.getJSON('/Business/SubPracticeGroup', { practiceGroup: selectedGroupId }, function (subGroups) {
        var subGroupsSelect = $('#SubPracticeGroupId');
        subGroupsSelect.empty();
        subGroupsSelect.append(
                $('<option/>')
                    .attr('value', '')
                    .text('Subgroup')
            );
        $.each(subGroups, function (index, subGroup) {
            subGroupsSelect.append(
                $('<option/>')
                    .attr('value', subGroup.Code)
                    .text(subGroup.Name)
            );
        });
    });
});
```

On submit if server side validation fails error message appears and values in SubPracticeGroupId dropdown goes blank. This also happen for the HTML I am generating dynamically using jQuery ajax. Is there a way to retain such values after server side validation?

Comment: Its because you send back the binded selected value to the `ActionResult` not the lists, because the lists aren't binded to anything.

Comment: you should use Ajax.BeginForm instead of Html.BeginForm

Comment: @ehsan Sajjad Using Ajax.BeginForm retains the value but all the error messages are lost. What should i do to show the error messages.

Comment: you are talking about validation messages??

Comment: Yes I am talking about validation messages.

Comment: @ehsan I figured out the way to show validation messages. Please add your comment in answers so that I can mark it as soultion

Comment: BTW why validation was not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **Ajax.BeginForm** instead of **Html.BeginForm**, as **Html.BeginForm** will do a full postback and you will not be able to retain them, by using **Ajax.BeginForm** the data will be posted asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it. I changed following Html.Begin form

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerNmae", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

to

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerNmae", new AjaxOptions
{
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter, 
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    OnFailure = "ShowFailureMessage",
    OnSuccess="Success",
    UpdateTargetId ="error",
}))
```

To show validation messages I created a partial view and bind that to same ViewModel as my parent view. _error.cshtml

```
    @model Project.ViewModels.VieModelName

   <div class="error" >
       @Html.ValidationSummary(false)
    </div>
```

In parent view added the div to show the validation messages. Id of that div would be same as defined in ajax parameters Parentview.cshtml

```
<div class="error" id="error" >
     @Html.ValidationSummary(false)
     @Html.Partial("_error")
 </div>
```

And finally in controller:

```
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
     .. Save logic
  }
  else
  {
     return PartialView("_error", VieModelName);
  }
```